# HowTo insert into tableName with select and specifying insert columns at Jooq?

Tags: jooq

I'm using Jooq to generate SQL
Here is resulting query

```sql
insert into MY_TABLE -- I want INSERT INTO(firstField,secondField)
select 
  ?, 
  ?
where not exists (
  select 1
  from MY_TABLE
  where (
    firstField = ?
  )
)
returning id
```

MY_TABLE DDL:

```
create table IF NOT EXISTS MY_TABLE
(
    id              SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstField         int          not null,
    secondField        int          not null
)
```

I can't make Jooq add field names next to `insert into MY_TABLE`

My builder:

```scala
    JooqBuilder.default()
      .insertInto(table("MY_TABLE")) 
      .select(
        select(
          param(classOf[Int]), // 1 
          param(classOf[Int]), // 2 
        
        )
          .whereNotExists(select(inline(1))
            .from(table("MY_TABLE"))
            .where(
              DSL.noCondition()
                .and(field("firstField", classOf[Long]).eq(0L))
                
            )
          ) 
    ).returning(field("id")).getSQL
```

I've tried

```
.insertInto(table("MY_TABLE"),field("firstField"), field("secondField"))
```

UPD:
I was confused by compiler exception.
The right solution is

````scala
```scala
    JooqBuilder.default()
      .insertInto(table("MY_TABLE"), 
          field("firstField",classOf[Int]),
          field("secondField",classOf[Int])
      ) 
      .select(
        select(
          param(classOf[Int]), 
          param(classOf[Int]) 
        
        )
          .whereNotExists(select(inline(1))
            .from(table("MY_TABLE"))
            .where(
              DSL.noCondition()
                .and(field("firstField", classOf[Long]).eq(0L))
                
            )
          ) 
    ).returning(field("id")).getSQL
````

The thing is that Jooq takes field types from `insertInto` and doesn't compile if `select` field types don't match.

I've tried

```scala
.insertInto(table("MY_TABLE"), 
          field("firstField"),
          field("secondField")
      )
```

and it didn't compile since no match with

```scala
.select(
        select(
          param(classOf[Int]), // 1 
          param(classOf[Int]) // 2 
        
        )
```

I've added types to insertInto fields and got match, two ints in insert, two ints in select.

Jooq generated expected query

```sql
insert into MY_TABLE -- I want INSERT INTO(firstField,secondField)
select 
  ?, 
  ?
where not exists (
  select 1
  from MY_TABLE
  where (
    firstField = ?
  )
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-select/

Comment: No, it uses generated code... I've seen that doc

Comment: @Capacytron: It doesn't matter if you're using generated code or not. The API is the same

Comment: @LukasEder appreciate your response, didn't figure out how to make it work for me. I've updated question

Comment: @Capacytron: Well, your update doesn't really have much to do with your question, though...?

Comment: I've updated it again. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Capacytron: And your second update is yet another question, not the same one. Can you please avoid editing questions and ask new ones instead? My answer answers your initial question. I'll be very happy to answer follow up questions and explain in detail, but if I have to edit my answer every time you edit your question, it will be very confusing for future readers of this set of question/answer edits

Comment: Hi, you've solved my initial problem. I've adopted your solution with InsertInto(table, field(name, class) to my builder code. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ just generates *exactly* the SQL you tell it to generate. You're not listing `firstField,secondField` in jOOQ, so jOOQ doesn't list them in SQL. To list them in jOOQ, just add:

```scala
  // ...
  .insertInto(table("MY_TABLE"), field("firstField", classOf[Long]), ...)
  // ...
```

Obviously, even without using the code generator, you can reuse expressions by assigning them to local variables:

```scala
val t = table("MY_TABLE")
val f1 = field("firstField", classOf[Long])
val f2 = field("secondField", classOf[Long])
```

And then:

```scala
  // ...
  .insertInto(t, f1, f2)
  // ...
```

#### Using the code generator

Note that if you were using the code generator, [which jOOQ recommends](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/), your query would be much simpler:

```scala
ctx.insertInto(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.FIRST_FIELD, MY_TABLE.SECOND_FIELD)
   .values(v1, v2)
   .onDuplicateKeyIgnore()
   .returningResult(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .fetch();
```

Comment: omg, so it's smart enough to figure out type signature of insertInto... and select columns.